# Accessing multiple databases from SQL Server 2008 R2 in my windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

How to access multiple databases from SQL Server 2008 R2 in my windows application?

i want to access multible databases from single sqlserver in my windows application.For ex:i want to select student details from DB1 and i want to select Employee details from DB2 both are used in my single windows application ,so what should i do?

Comment: You need to be more clear about your scenario. How and where do you want to access these databases from?

Comment: please clarify your questions, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @sampath, why and where do you want to access multiple databases?

Answer (score 2):

You'd better try to keep your entities in one database, but in case you can't or don't want to due to a reason, the solution would be to use multiple connection strings in your application.

And based on the ADO.Net choice you choose, there can be different ways to achieve so.

Edit: This is how I did it with `Linq-to-Sql`

I have two databases and each has one Table, here's the schema:

**TeachersDB** (first Database):
-Teachers {TeacherID [int], TeacherName[string]}

**StudentsDB** (second Database):
-Students {StudentID [int], TeacherID[int] StudentName[string]}

```
StudentsDataContext studentsDB = new StudentsDataContext();
TeachersDataContext teachersDB = new TeachersDataContext();
```

*so each student has one teacher (for the sake of simplicity)*

```
Student st;
Teacher t;

st = (from stu in studentsDB.Students
     where stu.StudentID == int.Parse(txtStudentID.Text)
     select stu).SingleOrDefault<Student>();

t = (from teach in teachersDB.Teachers
    where teach.TeacherID == st.TeacherID
     select teach).SingleOrDefault<Teacher>();

MessageBox.Show(t.TeacherName);
```

as you can see I got data from two tables (each in a seperate database) and saved them in memory (class objects st and t) and then worked with them and found the students teacher.

I hope it helps.

Comment: using(SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("FirstConnectionString"))
{
  DataTable dataFromA = //result from SELECT id, name FROM TableA
}


using(SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("SecondConnectionString"))
{
  DataTable dataFromB = //result from SELECT id, name FROM TableB
}

Comment: yes that's a way of doing it, but you need to store the data somewhere (like a DataSet) to be able to work with your data.

Comment: @sampath if you got my point now you can do it in any ado.net case you use, it doesn't matter if you are using a DataAdapter you can fill different objects and work with them.

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use different `connectionstrings` in which you set the `initial catalog` to the different db's.
Hardcoded in the code they will look like:

```
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=Db1;User   Id=user;Password=pass;")
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=Db2;User Id=user;Password=pass;")
```

and use the connectionstring for each specific query. Those you can add as well into your `app.config` or `web.config`.

Or add a `USE MyDbName` on top of your query when there's no `Initial Catalog` specified in your `connectionstring` ie `USE MyDbName SELECT * FROM MyTable` In this case you'll be using the same connectionstring for both databases.

Comment: sir tel me detail with code plz

Comment: sir actually i want to use configmanager so in this way solve my problem with detail explanation .thanks in advance

Comment: @sampath added an example of the connectionstrings for you. Im afraid I can't answer more specific based on the information you have given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 connection strings, 
sent it based on your need to the method and hook up your grid/data anywhere whereever its needed.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(<connstring>))
{
connection.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

command.CommandText = <query1>;
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

DataGrid1.DataSource = reader;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
}

command.CommandText = <query2>;
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{

DataGrid2.DataSource = reader;
DataGrid2.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Create an App.Config file and add the following in the appsettings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="appDSN" value="data source=SERVER-NAME;initial catalog=StudentDB;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;packet size=4096" />
    <add key="appDSN2" value="data source=SERVER-NAME2;initial catalog=EmpolyeeDB;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;packet size=4096" />
</appSettings>
```

The key is the name you give to your setting, the value is in this case the connectionstring

and use the following when connecting to retrieve data from both databases:

```
//
// In a using statement, acquire the SqlConnection as a resource.
//
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["appDSN1"]))
{
    //
    // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
    con.Open();
    //
    // The following code shows how you can use an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
    //
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Students", con))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
          //read through the first database
    }
    }
}

//
// In a using statement, acquire the SqlConnection as a resource.
//
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["appDSN2"]))
{
    //
    // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
    con.Open();
    //
    // The following code shows how you can use an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
    //
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employees", con))
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
          //read through the second database
    }
    }
```

This is the easy and old way using sqlreader. Using mahdi tahsildari way (Linq to SQL) is more of today.

Comment: here what is appDSN1 ? am nt getting

Comment: appDSN1 refers to the appsetting. You could use it like this:

Comment: using(SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["appDSN1"])) 
{ 
 DataTable dataFromA = result from SELECT id, name FROM TableA 
} 
using(SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["appDSN2"])) 
{ 
DataTable dataFromB = result from SELECT id, name FROM TableB 
}

Comment: You can get the appsetting key (the name of the key within the app.config of your project) which is your connectionstring. The connectionstring will than be used by the SQLConnection. Using once the first key and once the second key, You can select to the two databases. The connection information in this case is stored in the value of the app key.

Comment: thanks for every one alot....

Comment: Don't forget to mark an ansawer if usefull for future readers