# Return Table Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlclr

Currently work with multiple servers and need to return the results in a table, how can I do?
I intend to get data from each bank and return all through a single procedure.
Example, caught available space of the server and return in table format.
You must be in .NET

Comment: "*You must be in .NET*"?? ask it politely and show something you tried !!!

Comment: I do not know where to start.
clr know only send in text form, must return table type

Comment: What do you mean by "You must in .NET"? What are you trying to do? Please show an example as it is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

First create the links to other server

Example:

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'SecondServer', 
@srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname = N'SecondServer', 
@locallogin = NULL , 
@useself = N'True' ;
GO
```

Then you can create procedure that can query multiple server.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName
(
  @dateFrom datetime,
  @dateTo datetime
)
AS

BEGIN

SELECT * FROM  CurrentServerName.DatabaseName.TableName
UNION
SELECT * FROM SecondServerName.DatabaseName.TableName;

END
```

Comment: Correct.
It's not just these information I need, I need some information level system, which is idel use any IDE
So I intend to do in .NET

Comment: Thats was an reply to your question. Personally I would not go with Linked server. Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055314/accessing-multiple-databases-from-sql-server-2008-r2-in-my-windows-application